# Magento API + CloudFlare Successful?

Tags: api

Is anyone successfully using CloudFlare with Magento + Magento API?  We're troubleshooting intermittent corrupted API results despite having a CloudFlare rule for all API calls as documented here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-CloudFlare-with-your-API.  Our current thinking is to host Magento's admin/api url on a sub domain so we can turn CloudFlare off on this subdomain.

Comment: CloudFlare is a hack for a real architecture - not the best approach especially with Magento but there you go. Yes you can separate them that way - but still - not the real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have concluded that the Magento API will not work reliably with CloudFlare despite having CloudFlare rules in place.  Switching Magento admin/api to use a different subdomain e.g. myadminname.domain.com and making CloudFlare inactive resolved this issue.

However, Magento created duplicate front-end urls e.g. domain.com and myadminname.domain.com pages. Existing Magento extensions also broke.  So there's work to do just to make Magento admin work on the subdomain too.